# Get errors in routes.php file to pass them to another route

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5

I need to get errors passed to a route and pass them to another route by redirect.

In the exception handler I have:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return redirect('/')
        ->withErrors(['my-message-error']);

    //return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

In the routes.php file I have:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        // Here I need to get errors to pass to the "to-do-list"
        return redirect('to-do-list')->withErrors(WHAT?);
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
});
```

I want to redirect all the errors to the base url, and in the route I can switch users without losing messages.

**UPDATED**

I found out the solution. I can "reflash" error messages in this way.
In the routes.php file I use:

```
Session::reflash();  
return redirect('to-do-list');
```

"reflash" function does not work, this code actually works:

```
return redirect('to-do-list')->withErrors(Session::get('errors')->default);
```

Comment: what errors exactly? Just any exceptions?

Comment: Errors passed with withErrors. If its possible any exceptions, it would be good either.

Comment: withErrors accepts an `array` and is usually used when dealing with validation errors? I don't really understand what your goal is here, and what kind of errors you are referring to.

Comment: I redirect to the "/" route with errors (using withErrors). I need to get those errors and pass them to another route.

Comment: I understand that part, however what errors - do you have any examples of the errors you want to pass?

Comment: `return redirect('/')->withErrors(['my-message-error']);` I need to get this withErrors array and pass it to another route

Comment: So what you want to achieve is the error's session variable gets reflashed for every request?

Comment: Exact, I guess I got it with this: `return redirect('to-do-list')->withErrors(Session::get('errors')->default);`